# Error in date class

Tags: date

I am tr4ying to concatenate two date fields. But I'm getting this error: "Date expressions must use Integer or Long"

eg: System.debug(date.today()+date.today());

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly add two dates together to get a String. You have to convert them to Strings first. By "adding" (`+`) almost any type to a String, that calls the `toString` method on the non-String operand, and the result is a String. The following example works:

```
System.debug(date.today()+''+date.today());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide Integer value of Long value to add to your Date.

For example - `Date.today().addDays(1)` or `Date.today() + 1`

I am not sure what you are actually trying to achieve here. Please provide more information if it doesn't help.